# FabricConnectionDeniedException - Where do I setup Azure Service Fabric connections?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio Project Template that includes an Azure Service Fabric Project with a `StatelessService`.

In the boiler plate `Program` EntryPoint code, I'm getting a `FabricConnectionDeniedException`.  **Where do I setup the Connection Information or otherwise fix this exception?**  I'm running against the Local Cluster Manager.  I've looked through the various `.xml` config files but aren't seeing anything.  Do I need to whitelist my application in the Cluster Manager?

Here's the boiler plate code I copied from the Azure Service Fabric:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Creating a FabricRuntime connects this host process to the Service Fabric runtime.
            using (var fabricRuntime = System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.Create())
            {
                // The ServiceManifest.XML file defines one or more service type names.
                // RegisterServiceType maps a service type name to a .NET class.
                // When Service Fabric creates an instance of this service type,
                // an instance of the class is created in this host process.
                fabricRuntime.RegisterServiceType(
                    "RunSetManagerServiceType", 
                    typeof(RunSetManagerService));

                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(
                    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, 
                    typeof(RunSetManagerService).Name);

                // Prevents this host process from terminating to keep the service host process running.
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
           // !!!!!! GETTING FabricConnectionDeniedException HERE !!!!!
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

This is because you're running your service EXE outside of the Service Fabric runtime environment. When you compile your service into an EXE, you can't just execute it on its own; you have to "deploy" it the Service Fabric cluster where it will be executed for you by the Service Fabric runtime environment.

If you're deploying through Visual Studio, make sure your **application** project is set as the startup project, not the service project (the startup project will appear in **bold** in the Solution Explorer).

Also, **not related to the error you're seeing** but just a heads up: When you upgraded to the latest 2.0.135 SDK, you'll need to update your service registration code to use the new ServiceRuntime:

```
try
{
    ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("RunSetManagerServiceType",
        context => new RunSetManagerService(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(Stateless1).Name);

    // Prevents this host process from terminating so services keep running.
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
    throw;
}
```